# кодировка в NetBeans. Кириллица не всегда печатается правильно

Tags: java, maven, кодировка, кириллица

Вопрос подымался миллион раз, я знаю. Да и в сети тысяча и один ответ. Но это я решить смог.
Суть. Когда я собираю проект Ant и что-либо печатаю в консоль (кириллицей),

```
 System.out.println("привет");
```

работает ОК.
Однако при попытке создать проект maven и собрать им, вылазит пачка квадратов/мусора:

```
""C:\Apache\maven\bin\mvn.bat"" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
```

��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

пробовал многое: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` в переменных windows прописал, добавил это в параметр самого NetBeans при запуске.

В данном случае у меня отказывается запускаться Maven, судя по всему система ругается на отсутствие файла (я догадался), но как мне сделать нормальное отображение кириллицы?

Comment: Я подозреваю, что сама консоль работает в каком-нибудь ср866, и это на самом деле не проблемы мавена. Хотя эти ромбы, насколько помню, существуют только внутри UTF-8 для обозначения умерших символов. В общем, подтвердите/опровергните, что `chcp` **внутри этой сессии** возвращает 65001 или 866.

Comment: да, я тоже подозреваю cp866, только как мне узнать что возвращает chcp ? единственное место где я могу это запустить - cmd. Там да, возвращает 866

Comment: Как происходит сборка `maven`? Я в нетбинсе ни разу явой не занимался. Туда можно воткнуть какой-нибудь аналог `; chcp` в конец команды?

Comment: А `("привет");` ты в какой кодировке пишешь?

Comment: кодировка проекта utf-8. стало быть в ней и пишу. chcp в конце я не знаю как добавить :(

Comment: Пробовали `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`?

Comment: Я же написал это в первом сообщении. Да, я пробовал. Я также добавил в реетр windows автоматическую установку chcp 65001 при каждом старте

Comment: Есть ли возможность прогнать вручную те же команды прямо из консоли и посмотреть вывод?

Comment: та команда, которую создает NB довольно длинная. я её скопировал в батник, попытался выполнить из cmd но получил ошибку `the filename or extension is too long`. Странно, как же его NB выполняет?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить команду

```
chcp 1251
```

в самом начале файла mvn.bat